# Write a polynomial fraction from its either partial fraction or coefficients of numerator and denominator

Tags: math-mode, pgffor

I need to robustly generate the displayed equation from either

1-  the coefficients of numerator and denominator defined by `\NumCoeffMat` and `\DenCoeffMat`, respectively

2- or the partial fraction terms defined by `\PartialFraction`

[image]

P.S. The coefficient of the highest order in the denominator is always positive one, so it is not given in the arrays.

Any coefficient of zero should exclude its associated order of `s` from the written expression.

```
\documentclass{article}

\edef\NumCoeffMat{{4, 32, 62}} % numerator coefficients (i.e. numerator =  4s^2 + 32s + 62)
\edef\DenCoeffMat{{12, 47, 60}} % denominator coefficients (i.e. denominator = s^3 + 12s^2 + 47s + 60)

\def\PartialFraction{1/-3, 2/-4, 1/-5} % gain/coefficient and root (i.e. 1/(s+3) + 2/(s+4) + 1/(s+5) )

\begin{document}
    \[
    \frac{4\,s^2 + 32\,s + 62}{s^3 + 12\,s^2 + 47\,s + 60}
    \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: why the double `{{` for numerator and denominator and why not  1,12,47,60 ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I just copied it from an answer to a previous question of mine.

Comment: you give no link but if that denominator is encoded as 12,47,60 how do you encode 2s^3 ?  also your question is very unclear do you just want to encode cubics so have a fixed list with two commas that you can process with a fixed macro `\def\foo#1,#2,#3{...}` or do you want to process arbitrary order rational functions, so need to loop over a list of coefficients?

Comment: The double braces indicates a tikz array, which would make it easy to construct polynomials using \foreach.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I'd never even consider using tikz to answer this question:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the coefficient of the highest order is always one. I am on my phone now, so I can't write the link to my previous question, however, those arrays are looped over by foreach to draw some graph.

Comment: how can we tell that from the question? the coefficients then are rational not integer, if you can always normalise the leading coefficient to 1 ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The coefficients of both numerator and denominator always are integers and provided in the given macros. Only the coefficient of the denominator highest order is always positive one, and I updated my question to say so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a general macro to write polynomials. The first argument is the indeterminate and the second is the list of coefficients

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcount\degree
\newif\ifzero
\newif\ifcoeff

% \polynomial{<indeterminate>}{<list of coefficients>}
\newcommand*\polynomial[2]{%
  \global\degree=0\relax
  \foreach\x in {#2} {\global\advance\degree 1\relax}%
  \ifnum\degree=0
    0%
  \else
    \global\zerotrue
    \foreach\coeff in {#2} {%
      \global\advance\degree-1
      \coefffalse
      \ifnum\coeff=0 \else
        \ifnum\coeff>0 \ifzero\else+\fi\fi
        \ifnum\coeff=-1
          -\ifnum\degree=0 1\fi
        \else\ifnum\coeff=1
          \ifnum\degree=0 1\fi
        \else
          \coefftrue  
          \coeff
        \fi\fi 
        \ifnum\degree>0\relax\ifcoeff\,\fi{#1}\ifnum\degree>1^{\the\degree}\fi\fi
        \global\zerofalse
      \fi
    }%
    \ifzero 0\fi
  \fi
}

\newcommand\PartialFraction[2][s]{%
  \global\zerotrue
  \foreach \n/\r in {#2} {%
    \ifnum\n=0 \else
      \ifnum\n<0
        -\edef\n{\the\numexpr-\n\relax}%
      \else
        \ifzero\else +\fi
      \fi
      \global\zerofalse
      \frac{\n}{s\ifnum\r>0 -\r\else\ifnum\r<0 +\the\numexpr-\r\relax\fi\fi}%
    \fi}%
  \ifzero 0\fi
}

\begin{document}
\[
    \frac{\polynomial{s}{4,32,62}}{\polynomial{s}{1,12,47,60}}
\]
\[
    \PartialFraction{1/-3, 2/-4, 1/-5}
\]
\end{document}
```

The next macro allows you to give the coefficients the way you want

```
% \Fraction[<indeterminate> defaults to s]
\newcommand\Fraction[1][s]{%
  \begingroup
    \def\polyaux##1{{1,##1}}%
    \edef\next{\noexpand\frac{\unexpanded{\polynomial{#1}}\NumCoeffMat}{\unexpanded{\polynomial{#1}}\expandafter\polyaux\DenCoeffMat}}%
    \next
  \endgroup
}
\[
  \def\NumCoeffMat{{4, 32, 62}}  % numerator = 4s^2+32s+62 
  \def\DenCoeffMat{{12, 47, 60}} % denominator = s^3+12s^2+47s+60
  \Fraction
\]
```

Comment: If you don't mind, I took the liberty of fine-tuning your code to make it consistent with what I need.

Comment: For your first command `\polynomial`, how to redefine it to use either the tikz array `\NumCoeffMat` defined by `\def\NumCoeffMat{{12, 47, 60}}` as its argument or `{12,47,60}` as you already did?

Comment: You did well. I wrote too fast. I am not sure to understand your last question. Since the coefficients of the numerator and the denominator are not given in a consistent way, it is almost impossible to design a general macro which would take either an explicit list of coefficients or the list given in a macro which could include or not the first coefficient.

Comment: I edited back my code to match the fraction in your question.

Comment: I edited my answer and added the macro `\PartialFraction` for the second part of your question.

Comment: Actually, `\PartialFraction` is needed to calculate and typeset the whole fraction as done by `\polynomial`.

Answer (score 3):

using an expl3 clist....

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\NumCoeffMat{4, 32, 62} % numerator coefficients (i.e. numerator =  4s^2 + 32s + 62)
\def\DenCoeffMat{12, 47, 60} % denominator coefficients (i.e. denominator = s^3 + 12s^2 + 47s + 60)

\edef\DenCoeffMatX{1,\DenCoeffMat} % add the leading 1 back
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N\l_tmp_int
\tl_new:N\l_sep
\tl_set:Nn\l_sep{}

\def\z#1{
\int_set:Nn\l_tmp_int{\clist_count:N#1 - 1} % order of polynomial
\clist_map_inline:Nn#1{
\int_compare:nNnT{##1}> {0} % skip 0 terms
  {\l_sep                   % + except first term
   \int_compare:nNnT{##1}> {1}{##1\,} % skip coeff 1
  \int_compare:nNnT{\l_tmp_int}> {0}{
    s\int_compare:nNnT{\l_tmp_int}> {1}{^{\int_use:N\l_tmp_int}}}} % skip power 1
\int_decr:N\l_tmp_int
\tl_set:Nn\l_sep{+}
}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\frac{\z\NumCoeffMat}{\z\DenCoeffMatX}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This expands a polynomial using `\foreach`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\edef\NumCoeffMat{{4, 32, 62}}% numerator coefficients (i.e. numerator =  4s^2 + 32s + 62)

\newcounter{exponent}
\newcommand{\poly}[1]{\bgroup
  \setcounter{exponent}{-1}%
  \def\zero{0}%
  \def\one{1}%
  \expandafter\edef\expandafter\list#1
  \foreach \x in \list {\stepcounter{exponent}}% max exponent
  \foreach \x in \list {\ifnum\value{exponent}>0 
    \ifx\x\zero \else
      \ifx\x\one \else \x \fi
      \ifnum\value{exponent}>1 s^\theexponent +
      \else s +
      \fi
    \fi
  \else \x% last coeficient in polynomial
  \fi
  \addtocounter{exponent}{-1}}%
\egroup}
  

\begin{document}
    
    $\poly{\NumCoeffMat}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you need `\ifnum`, `\if\x\zero` is true if `\x` is 11

Comment: Can you keep `\NumCoeffMat` as tikz array by having double curly braces around its content? Or internally check for an outer pair of curly braces, then remove it if existing without changing `\NumCoeffMat` as tikz array.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - At the time I was worried about decimals.  \if sure isn't good for much!

Answer (score 2):

As an exercise, I tried to rewrite the answer of David Carlisle with my [`functional`](https://ctan.org/pkg/functional) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{functional}

\def\NumCoeffMat{4, 32, 62} % numerator coefficients (i.e. numerator =  4s^2 + 32s + 62)
\def\DenCoeffMat{12, 47, 60} % denominator coefficients (i.e. denominator = s^3 + 12s^2 + 47s + 60)

\edef\DenCoeffMatX{1,\DenCoeffMat} % add the leading 1 back

\IgnoreSpacesOn

\PrgNewFunction \Z {M} {
  \IntSet \lTmpaInt {\ClistVarCount #1}
  \IntDecr \lTmpaInt
  \ClistClear \lTmpaClist
  \ClistVarMapInline #1 {
    \IntCompareTF {##1} > {0} {
      \IntCompareTF {##1} > {1} {
        \TlSet \lTmpaTl {##1}
      }{
        \TlSet \lTmpaTl {}
      }
      \IntCompareTF {\lTmpaInt} > {1} {
        \TlPutRight \lTmpaTl {\Expand{s^{\OnlyValue\lTmpaInt}}}
      }{
        \IntCompareTF {\lTmpaInt} = {1} {
          \TlPutRight \lTmpaTl {s}
        } { }
      }
      \ClistPutRight \lTmpaClist {\Value\lTmpaTl}
    } { }
    \IntDecr \lTmpaInt
  }
  \ClistVarJoin \lTmpaClist {+}
}

\IgnoreSpacesOff

\begin{document}

\[ \frac{\Z\NumCoeffMat}{\Z\DenCoeffMatX} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your packages are always neat and clean. Many thanks for your contribution to the community