# foreach: print a polynomial using its terms

Tags: foreach

How to make the following work to have the output

`5 x V^3 + 7 x V + 9`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\mypower}{3, 2, 1, 0}
    \newcommand{\mycoeff}{5, 0, 7, 9}
    $
    \foreach \c/\p in \mycoeff/\mypower{
        \c \times V^{\p}
    }
    $
\end{document}
```

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/622275/write-a-polynomial-fraction-from-its-either-partial-fraction-or-coefficients-of

Comment: @JohnKormylo Awkwardly, this is my own question I forgot I asked before.

Answer (score 1):

Here, I use `listofitems` to accomplish the task.  I also build in additional logic to handle negative coefficients, exclude terms with zero coefficients, and properly render powers of `V^0` (as no `\times 1` multiplier) and `V^1` (as `V`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\mypoly{%
    \foreachitem \z \in \mycoeff[]{%
      \ifnum\zcnt=1\else\ifnum\z>0+\fi\fi
      \ifnum\z=0 \else\z 
        \ifnum\mypower[\zcnt]=0\else\times V
          \ifnum\mypower[\zcnt]=1\else^{\mypower[\zcnt]}%
      \fi\fi\fi
    }%
}
\begin{document}
    \readlist*\mypower{3, 2, 1, 0}
    \readlist*\mycoeff{5, 0, -7, 9}
    $\mypoly$

    \readlist*\mycoeff{5, 2, 7, 9}
    $\mypoly$

    \readlist*\mycoeff{5, 2, 7, 0}
    $\mypoly$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your help. However, I would like to get an answer as close as possible to my question to help me integrate it in my original document.

Comment: @Diaa I understand.  I'm sure someone will solve it with the approach you require.